# Combining OSM tiles with selective ultra high zoom graphics from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: mapbox, adobe-illustrator, tilemill

What's the best way to combine regular OSM-TileMill-Mapbox tiles with some Adobe Illustrator vector diagrams?

e.g. let's say I have a typical map of a city, and I want to add one special feature: for the city's theme park, I want to have an extra zoom level where a graphic designer will overlay the theme park rides.

What would be an efficient process for doing this? And actually I will have 100's of special features eventually, not just one.

Also wondering if using TileMill 2's vector tiles would have an advantage in this case too.

Comment: Vector tiles have nothing to do with this task. You would need to georeference your diagrams, converting to one of [those OGR formats]. Then add resulting files as a layer. Alas, I cannot recommend anything for vector georeferencing: try browsing through [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points), [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22691/how-to-georeference-a-dxf) or [this](http://gisforthought.com/georeferencing-vector-data-using-qgis-and-ogr2ogr/) pages.

Comment: @IljaZverev so the best way would actually be to export the vector diagrams to a raster format before trying to integrate them with TileMill?

Comment: It would be the easiest way (just make sure resolution is high enough).

Comment: Although, if I have this extra layer as raster format, would that stop me from using TM2 and vector tiles for all the other zoom levels?

Comment: No, those are different matters, both TM1 and TM2 should support vector and raster GDAL layers regardless of types of other layers.